# Returning String in RequestFactory

Tags: gwt

I'm returning a string from the server side, it's corresponding request context method is also available, but i'm getting No operation found in request exception, any idea ??

Can't we return string in requestfactory ?

Comment: Of course you can return a `String`! Show your code, it must be something simple (something like: is your server-side method `public`?)

Comment: It's working when i removed public in the service, the service contains other methods with entities too.

Comment: But why it's not working when it was public, any ideas ??

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can return a String from a request factory call.

Are you getting other requests back and only this one is failing?  If so check for something like Thomas Broyer suggested with the service method.

Do you have the GWT 2.4 validator set up  http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/RequestFactoryInterfaceValidation .  This can tell you if your shared request matches your service.